# Read raw Date string in a Custom JsonConverter of JSON.net

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, asp.net-web-api2, customserializer

I have an input date string in ISO 8601 format (`2020-07-23T09:42:02.694Z`). And in my Controller the Property is defined as `DateTime`. I have written a custom date converter to convert the date to LocalTime zone (this is unusual).

```
public class UTCtoUnspecifiedDateConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader != null 
            && reader.Value != null 
            && this.CanConvert(objectType) 
            && this.CanRead 
            && typeof(DateTime) == reader.Value.GetType())
        {
            return DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)reader.Value, DateTimeKind.Unspecified).ToLocalTime();
        }
        else
        {
            return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get the raw string that I am sending from the Client in this converter?
Basically I want to check if there is a `Z` at the end or not.

While debugging I saw a `private` property on the `reader` which stores this information. Any way to get this here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a custom `JsonConverter` to handle dates, you need to set the [`DatePraseHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_DateParseHandling.htm) setting to `None`.

```
var jsonSettings = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
jsonSettings.Converters.Add(new UTCtoUnspecifiedDateConverter());
jsonSettings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;
```

Then, in your converter, you will get date values from the `reader` as strings which you can parse using `DateTime.TryParse` or `DateTime.TryParseExact`.

As an aside, there are some checks you are making inside of `ReadJson` that are not necessary.  You shouldn't need to call `CanConvert` or `CanRead`, because Json.Net does that for you in order to determine whether to call `ReadJson` in the first place.  Also, the `reader` passed to `ReadJson` will never be null, so you don't need to check for that either.  So that simplifies the code quite a bit.

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    if (reader.Value is string && 
        DateTime.TryParseExact((string)reader.Value, DateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime date))
    {
        return DateTime.SpecifyKind(date, DateTimeKind.Unspecified).ToLocalTime();
    }
    else
    {
        return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
    }
}
```